# Concatenating dataframe on column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataset having one column in common, `User`.
However one dataset, `df2`, has user with no duplicates, while `df1` has all the users.

```
**df1**

User          Text
carl_22       bla bla bla
Renoir_J54    bla bla bla 1
David         bla bla bla 2
carl_22       bla bla bla 3
David         bla bla bla 4
...


**df2**

User          Value
carl_22       43
Renoir_J54    23
David         99
...
```

I would like to assign to each user in `df1` the corresponding `Value` in `df2`:

```
User          Text              Value
carl_22       bla bla bla       43
Renoir_J54    bla bla bla 1     23
David         bla bla bla 2     99
carl_22       bla bla bla 3     43
David         bla bla bla 4     99
...
```

I used `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')` but the output is different from my expected one. I do not know if I did something wrong: maybe because `User, Text` in `df1` and `User, Value` in `df2` are columns and not indices, or in the use of `concat`.

Can you please tell me if you spot any issue within my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
pd.merge(df1, df2,how='inner')
```